# How to make BrowserLink work with .NET Core in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, browser-link

BrowserLink doesn't seem to work with .NET Core 2.1.5 at all.

Per [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52207185/browserlink-tooling-doesnt-work-with-asp-net-core-2-1) about a somewhat earlier version of the .NET Core, I got the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink` package from nuget and now, under Dependencies/Nuget, it displays this reference twice: once under Microsoft.AspNetCore.All and once on its own.

[image]

Oddly enough, the BrowserLink code is injected into the web page, but whenever I save a change to .cshtml file or a css file, no refresh happens.

If I click Refresh on the Browser Link Dashboard, it asks me if I want to stop debugging.

[image]
[image]

Is BrowserLink simply broken for .NET Core or am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 1):

Dunno if you still need this but running as debug is different than the browser link. [Here is an snippit showing the difference between browse and debug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/using-browserlink?view=aspnetcore-2.2) You can either **Debug** or **Browse**.

Comment: I got it to work using the method you described...but the feature we lost is that the web pages refresh when you press Ctrl-S.  Now you have to click that Refresh BrowserLink button (or bind it to something).